# Unable to install firebase crashlytics with swift package manager

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, swift-package-manager

[image]

while adding swift package manager for firebase crashlytics shows failing where as need to use crashlytics in project

Comment: my fails with: the target 'gRPC-Core' in product 'gRPC-cpp' contains unsafe build flags.. when I try to build.. same issue as yours ?

Answer (score 2):

You can disregard that failing notice from the GitHub home page.

It indicates a recently added flaky unit test that is currently being addressed at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/9797.

There are no known issues with Crashlytics and its Swift Package Manager integration.

Comment: Thou it doesn't work for me as well, I can add by cocoapods but when add by SPM it fails with the target 'gRPC-Core' in product 'gRPC-cpp' contains unsafe build flags... Looks like different issue then here..

Comment: Yep - that's the now resolved https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9818. See the resolution there.